# Is it possible to recover a deleted branch that you deleted using the Github website?

Tags: git, github

I accidentally deleted a branch on Github using this [tutorial](https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/github-delete-branch). The gif is mainly what I followed. Is there a way to undo this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you ever checked out this branch locally you can use `git reflog` to get back to it and recreate it.

```
$ git reflog
434f93d (HEAD -> CMD-28) HEAD@{0}: reset: moving ...
4544567 HEAD@{1}: reset: moving ...
434f93d (HEAD -> CMD-28) HEAD@{2}: rebase (finish): returning ...
434f93d (HEAD -> CMD-28) HEAD@{3}: rebase (pick): WIP x64 DEBUG
```

note commit id in the left column and do `git checkout -b <branchName> <commitId>`

Then `git push` it back to GitHub